# Conversion of nullable double variable to String in VB.NET

Tags: string, vb.net, double, nullable

Recently I came across a weird behaviour of a nullable double. As I need to turn a nullable variable into string with precisely set digits I am using method `.ToString(format)`. When I apply this method on the aforementioned nullable variable instead of getting converted number as I need, I get only the first digit of this number (example is given bellow). Of course I can cast the nullable to double and it solves it, but why is it happening though. Thank you very much for your input.

Example:

```
'Nullable Double
Dim value As Double? = 867
Dim convertedValue As String = value.ToString("0.00000")
Console.WriteLine(convertedValue)
'Output: 8

'Not nullable Double
Dim value As Double = 867
Dim convertedValue As String = value.ToString("0.00000")
Console.WriteLine(convertedValue)
'Output: 867.00000
```

Comment: That code wouldn't even compile with `Option Strict On`, which it should pretty much ALWAYS be. You should turn it `On` in the project properties and also in the IDE options, so it will be `On` by default for future projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you're trying to call doesn't exist. A `Double?` is actually a `Nullable(Of Double)`. Any method you call on that has to be a member of the `Nullable(Of T)` structure. How could that type have a `ToString` overload that took a numeric format string as an argument when `T` could be a non-numeric type? Here's the documentation for the `Nullable(Of T).ToString` method:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.tostring?view=net-5.0

As you can see, there is no such overload, unlike for the `Double` type:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=net-5.0

If you want to use a numeric format string then you need a number and a `Double?` is not a number. Here's a method you can use that will format the value as a number if it is one and normally otherwise:

```vb
Private Function FormatNullableDouble(number As Double?, format As String) As String
    Return If(number.HasValue,
              number.Value.ToString(format),
              number.ToString())
End Function
```

You might call that like this:

```vb
Dim convertedValue As String = FormatNullableDouble(value, "0.00000")
```

EDIIT:

To be clear, because you have `Option Strict Off`, the compiler is ignoring that your code doesn't make sense and assumes that it will at run time. When run time comes around, the system tries its best to find a way to make it work. What it actually comes up with is that this:

```vb
value.ToString("0.00000")
```

actually means this:

```vb
value.ToString().Chars(CInt("0.00000"))
```

In VB, you can omit the parentheses on a method call if there are no arguments so this:

```vb
value.ToString
```

is equivalent to this:

```vb
value.ToString()
```

By assuming that you have omitted the parentheses, the system can make that `ToString` call make sense, so it does that.

Now it just has to do something with the format string in the parentheses. The preceding `ToString` call returns a `String` and you can index a `String` to get a `Char` value at that index, so it assumes that that is what you're trying to do. It converts your format string to an `Integer` and then gets the `Char` from the `String` at that index. That is why a value of 867 produces 8 as the output. You are converting the number 867 to a `String`, then converting the `String` `"0.00000"` to an `Integer` to get 0, then getting the the `Char` at index 0 from the `String` `"867"`, which is `"8"c`.

All that is happening because you didn't turn `Option Strict On`, which tells the system to make the best guess it can to make bad code work.

Comment: I already created an extension method. I was only wondering why is it happening. Thank you very much for your answer. It is all clear now.

Comment: @PepaZdepa, I have added a detailed explanation of exactly what's happening and why.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. This is greatly appreciated!